# How to animate a jQueryUI positioned element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-animate

I have an element that I have positioned using jqueryUI's position.

I need to be able to animate this element by adjusting the offset (so that it remains relative to another element which is specified when initialising jQueryUI position.

I am positioning the element as shown:-

```
$('#toparrow').position ({

            of: $('#relative_element'),
            my: 'center top',
            at: 'center top',
            offset: "0 0"

        })
```

And would like to aniate the offset to '0 -30'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it's positioned, you can do a relative animation:

```
$('#toparrow').position({
  of: $('#relative_element'),
  my: 'center top',
  at: 'center top',
  offset: '0 0'
});

$('#toparrow').animate({
    top: '-=30px'
});
```

Due to the confusion of missing an = sign there, here's a jsfiddle to illustrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/Vz4WV/

Comment: Thanks bryan, but unfortunately this wont have the effect that I want as I need to animate the 'top' property.  This would of course be fine for one element however I am dynamically generating many of these elements, which get displayed one under another.  Meaning that the 'top' property would end up being the same for all of the elements.  I need the element to move 30px from it's original position rather then move to 30px from the top, if that makes sense.  It's my fault for not being clearer in my question, my apologies.

Comment: Okay, I've changed it to do. And as far as animating it from it's original position, it does. That's why it's a *relative* animation. That's what the '-30px' does. It tells jQuery to animate, from *wherever it currently it*, -30px upwards.

Comment: Sorry...I should mention that I am using position:absolute when styling the elements in order to not have them effect any surrounding elements,  Your solution, of course works with them set to position:relative, unfortunately this is not suitable in this case and with position:absolute set via css (in order to stack the elements on top of the page layout) they all aniate to the same height rather the -30px relative to the original positon.  Again my apologies for not giving enough detail.

Comment: My bad, I missed a character (an = sign). It should do what you want now

Comment: Fantastic! it worked perfectly!  And so simple too... I actually had no idea you could do that to force a relative animation.  Many thanks Bryan, it's much appreciated.